# How to define a series of bash commands as a string?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, grep, zsh

Right now some of the code in my .zshrc file looks like this:

```
inetFunction(){
    echo ${LRED}IP Address:${NC}
    ifconfig en0 | grep "inet " | awk '{print $2}'
}
```

$LRED is defined as changing the color to Light Red, and $NC is setting it back to normal. I implement the inetFunction with the code `alias inet='inetFunction'`. The output of the command is

```
IP Address:
xx.x.xx.xxx
```

where the "IP Address:" is in red. I wanted to make the IP Address green, but for some reason, when I try any of these, it doesn't work:

```
${GREEN}ifconfig en0 | grep "inet " | awk '{print $2}'

ifconfig en0 | grep "inet " | ${GREEN}awk '{print $2}'

${GREEN}ifconfig en0 | grep "inet " | awk '{${GREEN} print $2}'
```

I even tried setting the whole thing to a variable like:

```
variable='ifconfig en0 | grep "inet " | awk '{print $2}''
```

and then trying to do `echo ${GREEN} $variable`, but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you know that grep|awk is a silly anti-pattern? awk can do the grepping: `ifconfig en0 | awk '/inet / {print $1}'`. Saves an expensive fork and pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$GREEN` needs to be echoed. It's a set of ANSI color codes that your terminal recognizes as a signal to change the text color.

```
echo -n "$GREEN"
ifconfig en0 | grep "inet " | awk '{print $2}'
echo -n "$NC"
```

Or, condensed:

```
echo "$GREEN$(ifconfig en0 | grep "inet " | awk '{print $2}')$NC"
```

Also, as @Jens points out you can combine the grep and awk commands like so:

```
echo "$GREEN$(ifconfig en0 | awk '/inet / {print $2}')$NC"
```

Answer (score 0):

As already noted in [John Kugelman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36779576/2992551) `${GREEN}` needs to be printed in order to take affect.

As you are running `awk` anyway, you can just let it do the work:

```
ifconfig en0 | awk '/inet / {print "'${GREEN}'" $2 "'${NC}'"}'
ifconfig eno1 | awk "/inet / {print \"${GREEN}\" \$2 \"${NC}\"}"
```

This allows for more control what to color, especially with more complex `awk` programs.

Obviously the quoting necessary for that is anything but beautiful. `$2` needs to be quoted from the shell, so that it can be recognized by `awk`. `${GREEN}` and `${NC}` must not be quoted from the shell, so that they can be replaced by the shell. But as they are now just strings to `awk`, they need to be inside double quotes for `awk`; these double quotes need also need to be quoted from the shell.

To simplyfy this you can pass set variables for `awk` on the command line with the `-v variable=value` parameter:

```
ifconfig en0 | awk -v green="$GREEN" -v nc="$NC" '/inet / {print green $2 nc}'
```